# Drupal Mollie Payment no rules trigger

Tags: 7, commerce, rules, payment-gateways

We are working on a drupal ecommerce subscription service.

Modules: Commerce, Commerce Mollie, Payment etc..

Everything works 99%.

After finishing the payment the user needs to get the right role + a message.

This works with the default test creditcard payment.

But the commerce mollie integration module, is not triggering any rule after finishing the payment.

This is a real problem for us.

***Screenshots:***

[image]

[image]
[image]

**UPDATE**

[image]

[image]

https://www.drupal.org/project/mollie_payment
https://www.drupal.org/project/payment_commerce
https://www.drupal.org/project/payment

I would love any help, if there is information missing tell me!

Thank you guys.

Comment: I don't understand your language. Can you please install [admin_language](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_language) and retake the screenshots, this time in english?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use event named `order_paid_in_full`.

the mollie module does not take of that, it just create the transactions. 
(take a look at `payment` tab in the order)

So you have two options:

- Create you own rule, based on the event above, and grant the user the role.
- Use [commerce_license](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_license) module - it has a role module, and this is what you need.

Comment: Hello @JonnieJS,

I update my post with 2 screen shots of the Payment tab in a order and the rule i made, but nothing is being triggerd mmh?